# Are there any iphone/ipad camera hardware filters that can be controlled by an App?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, camera, hardware

I posted [this same question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50725/are-there-any-camera-hardware-filters-that-can-be-controlled-by-an-app/50726#50726) on apple.stackexchange... maybe here it fits better.

Does anyone know if in the iPhone (any version) there are any camera/CCD hardware filters (eg. polarizing filter, IR filter, bandpass filter) that can be controlled via software?

If so, how can I do and/or where can I find docs about it? I have written one iPad App using XCode, so I'm not totally newbie.

Thanks for any help.

---

**Edit**

I'm trying to develop an App, so I'm assuming there are **no external hardware/filters** attached to the device or the camera, just the iPhone/iPad with its standard hardware.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to replicate an IR filter using just data from visible wavelengths picked up by the camera. Same with a polarizing filter. You can't create data where none exist. The iPhone lacks hardware controls for this, short of you adding your own external lens / filter assemblies to the camera. Even manually setting the exposure level of the iPhone camera is a bear to do.

Comment: @BradLarson I see that there's no way to create an IR image from normal light conditions... that's not what I'm trying to achieve (we're not on wizardry.stackexchange.com :) In fact, my question was "is there any hardware filter that can be triggered via software?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the CIFilter class references, this can be used to achieve your goal. There are many different filters available, and I believe they can be applied in real time, or at least within milliseconds of real time.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Specifically, a list of all available CIFilters can be found here.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html

Comment: The list I've provided includes all available CIFilters and I don't believe there is a built in IR filter, so you'll probably have to explore your options for making a custom one, and are you connecting to IR hardware or just trying to simulate the IR look?

Comment: @PaoloStefan Yeah sorry I can't be much more help, CIFilter's really your only option for this that I'm aware of, I'd just play around with the available filters and see what you can come up with. Although there isn't an out of the box IR filter, I don't see any reason why it couldn't be replicated through combination of others.